# Remainder term in Taylor series expansion of $(1+t^2)^{-1}$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series expansion of $(1+t^2)^{-1}$ is given by

$
1-t^{2}+t^{4}-t^{6}+\ldots
$

A hint in Section 1.1, Exercise 9 in Asymptotic Analysis by Murray gives a remainder term for a truncated Taylor series

$
1-t^{2}+t^{4}-t^{6}+\ldots+(-1)^{n-1}t^{2n-2} + \frac{(-1)^{n}t^{2n}}{1+t^{2}}
$

My first instinct was to look at [identities for geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) but could not get anything in a form that resembled $\frac{(-1)^{n}t^{2n}}{1+t^{2}}$

Comment: if we are allowed to use Taylor's theorem, the remainder term is $(-1)^{n}\xi^{2n}$ for some $\xi \in (0,t)$.

But you can write the remainder as $(1+t^2)^{-1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-t^2)^k$ and use the geometric series formulae to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results from a high-school identity (which also yields the formula for the partial sums of the geometric series):
$$1-u^n=(1-u)(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1}),\enspace\text{whence}\quad\frac1{1-u}=1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1}+\frac{u^n}{1-u}.$$
Now set $u=-t^2$ to obtain instantly:
$$\frac1{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}t^{2(n-1)}+\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{1+t^2}$$